# Understanding the correct use of !$omp parallel do reduction(...)

Tags: fortran, fortran90, openmp

I am trying to write a program that counts the number of primes between 1 and some number `n` in Fortran 90 utilizing OpenMP. The nested loop just counts the numbers that are not prime. I want to use an `omp parallel do` to speed this up. As far as I understand, since I am just counting numbers that are not prime, it is appropriate to just use something like `!$omp parallel do reduction(+:not_primes)`. When I run the code below in serial without the `!$omp lines` I get the following output

```
 Primes:        5134
 OpenMP time elapsed  0.49368596076965332
```

but when I include the !$omp lines I get

```
 Primes: -1606400834
 OpenMP time elapsed  0.37933206558227539
```

Have I used the `parallel do` correctly here? (apparently not, but why?) Thanks!

```
program prime_counter

integer n, not_primes, i, j
real*8 :: ostart,oend, omp_get_wtime

ostart = omp_get_wtime()
n=50000

!$omp parallel do reduction(+:not_primes)
do i=2,n
    do j=2,i-1
        if(mod(i,j)==0) then
            not_primes= not_primes+1
            exit
        end if
    end do
end do
!$omp end parallel do


print*, 'Primes:', n-not_primes
oend = omp_get_wtime()
write(*,*) 'OpenMP time elapsed', oend-ostart

end program
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not initialize `not_primes` anywhere, it is undefined. The usage of the OpenMP reduction is OK. The index `j` should be marked as private, I normally mark all indexes as private, but that is not necessary.

```
not_primes = 0

!$omp parallel do reduction(+:not_primes) private(i,j)
```